# jquery ui slider weird behavior, slide values goes above minimum and under maximum

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am using jquery ui slider and make it smaller. When I slide it to the minimum, its value is go above the `min` value and when I slide it to maximum, its value is fall under the `max` value.

So the case is like this:

- **Minimum slide:** value goes to `0` and then `1`.
- **Maximum slide:** value goes to `500` and then `499`

What makes that weird behaviors and how to solve it?

--- **EDIT:** ---

It happens if I use the `slide` event type binding like this example:

```
$(".slider").on("slide", function(){
   var value = $(this).slider("value");
   $(this).closest(".item-wrapper").find(".input-text").val(value);
});
```

Is that a bug?

--- **end of edit** ---

Here is my codes:

**CSS:**

```
.sliderwrapper {
  float: right;
  width: 125px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0; 
}

#sliderwrap {
  margin: 15px 0 0 0; 
}

.ui-slider-horizontal {
    height: 6px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background: #f26522;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    top: -3.5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
  margin-left: -2.5px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="sliderwrap" class="sliderwrapper">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".slider").slider({
  value: val,
  min: 0,
  max: 500,
  step: 1
});
```

Comment: The code you have here appears to work for me.  If you're performing any other logic while displaying the slider value, you should include it in your question.  Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nsngxj3k/) using your code with an extra step to display the slider value.  If you're not doing extra logic, it may be a bug in the version of JQuery UI you're using

Comment: It seem it was caused by `slide` event type binding.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `slide` event is triggered only when `handle` is actually sliding, and at some interval, so that's hard to pinpoint. So especially when your range is high and the slider is small, it'll be triggered on a value before the `handle` stops and once it stops, the event isn't triggered anymore. To solve this you can add same function on `stop`. Like this:

```
$(".slider").slider({
    value: 20,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (e, ui) {
        var value = $(this).slider("value");
        $(".input-text").val(value);
    },
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        var value = $(this).slider("value");
        $(".input-text").val(value);
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kj0gsdL4/1/